# How to remove nan values from a list of values inside a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.09034446  0.16660596  0.20366712
0.21721049  0.22288556  0.2647726   0.30133098  0.35875865  0.67048766
0.83591387  0.84130192  1.00343632  1.08201832  1.32280598  3.71048433
4.92399325  5.7334934   5.78915343  5.79743345 11.87101934         nan
nan         nan         nan         nan]
In this list, I want to remove nan values and keep only the floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

if your nan values are np.nan use this

```
l = [x for x in yourlist if ~np.isnan(x)]
```

if they are just nans use this

```
cleanedList = [x for x in yourlist if str(x) != 'nan']
```